# Adding a div and two spans to Select2 dropdown options for better alignment

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been styling a Select2 box for hours because I thought it would be fairly easy to add html elements like divs and spans inside the dropdown options. I have been reading the https://select2.org/dropdown section over and over again and been looking up examples of Select2 templates made by other people but I can’t figure this out by myself.

I simply need the text as in the image below aligned as you see it. The size on the left, the price on the right with a little extra space on the right because of the arrow.

Can someone point me in the right direction here? **Edit: Got the script working.** *I am once again getting a script error and can’t find out what is wrong, so the snippet isn’t working at the moment.*

[image: Photoshopped]

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
            placeholder: 'Kies formaat en bekijk prijzen',
      allowClear: true,
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      multiple: true
    });
});

$('.js-example-basic-multiple').on('select2:opening select2:closing', function( event ) {
    var $searchfield = $(this).parent().find('.select2-search__field');
    $searchfield.prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```css
#main-container {
    width: 100%;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color: #0A0A0A;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color: #0A0A0A;
   opacity: 1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color: #0A0A0A;
   opacity: 1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color: #0A0A0A;
}
::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
   color: #0A0A0A;
}

::placeholder { /* Most modern browsers support this now. */
   color: #0A0A0A;
   opacity: 1;
}

.option-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear {
    display: none;
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {P
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.select2-selection--multiple:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    top: 42%;
    border-top: 5px solid #0A0A0A;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
}

.select2-container--open .select2-selection--multiple:before { 
        border-top:0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0A0A0A;
}

.select2.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 42px;
}

.select2.select2-container .select2-selection {
    outline: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.select2-results__option {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 42px;
  font-family: mada;
}

.select2.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  color: #0A0A0A;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__display {
    padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.select2.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice .select2-selection__choice__remove {
    background: #0A0A0A;
    color: #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  border: none;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border: 1px solid #0A0A0A;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.select2-container {
    min-width: 49%;
    /*border-right: 1px solid #0A0A0A;*/
  /*overflow-x: auto;*/
}

.select2-container--focus .select2-search--inline {
    display: none !important;
}

/*
.select2-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.select2-container {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}*/

.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
    background: #e6e6e6;
  height: 42px !important;
  max-width: 98%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: mada;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.select2-search--inline {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

input[type="text"]:disabled,
textarea:disabled {
  color: #0A0A0A;
  opacity: 1;
}

.select2-container .select2-dropdown {
    border: 0;
}

.select2-container .select2-dropdown .select2-results ul {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    border: 1px solid #0A0A0A;
  border-top: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--selected {
    background: #0A0A0A;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}

.select2.select2-container .select2-selection .select2-selection__rendered {
    color: #0A0A0A;
}

.select2-container .select2-dropdown .select2-results ul .select2-results__option--highlighted[aria-selected] {
    background: #0A0A0A;
    color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main-container">
<select id="Namiddag" name="Namiddag" data-name="Namiddag" data-placeholder="Kies formaat en bekijk prijzen" multiple="multiple" class="js-example-basic-multiple">
  <option id="13x19namiddag" value="13x19 cm / €12,50|€12,50">13x19 cm / €12,50</option>
  <option id="20x30namiddag" value="20x30 cm / €22,50|€22,50">20x30 cm / €22,50</option>
  <option id="30x45namiddag" value="30x45 cm / €32,50|€32,50">30x45 cm / €32,50</option>
</select>
<select id="Onderweg" name="Onderweg" data-name="Onderweg" data-placeholder="Kies formaat en bekijk prijzen" multiple="multiple" class="js-example-basic-multiple">
  <option id="13x19onderweg" value="13x19 cm / €12,50|€12,50">13x19 cm / €12,50</option>
  <option id="20x30onderweg" value="20x30 cm / €22,50|€22,50">20x30 cm / €22,50</option>
  <option id="30x45onderweg" value="30x45 cm / €32,50|€32,50">30x45 cm / €32,50</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simplified way of doing this just using the templateResult example in the docs, and using the option text to split it into two spans.

```js
function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }
  
  var text = state.text.split(',')
  var $state = $(
    `<span>${text[0]}</span><span>${text[1]}</span>`
  );
  return $state;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
    placeholder: 'Kies formaat en bekijk prijzen',
    allowClear: true,
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    multiple: true,
    templateResult: formatState
  });
});
```

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.select2 {
  width: 300px!important;
}

.select2-results__option {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div id="main-container">
  <select id="Namiddag" name="Namiddag" data-name="Namiddag" data-placeholder="Kies formaat en bekijk prijzen" multiple="multiple" class="js-example-basic-multiple">
    <option id="13x19namiddag" value="13x19 cm / €12,50|€12,50">13x19 cm,€12,50</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: is there however a way to also output the text the same way  in the selected field? Because I have the selected fields set to full width. See updated post for a image.

Comment: Never mind! I got what I want and even better :D